# Duplicate resource Wildfly

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I'm getting below error in Wildfly 8.2:

```
05:17:12,202 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.2.Final
05:17:12,285 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015899: WildFly 8.2.0.Final "Tweek" starting
05:17:13,199 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 12) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "ExampleDS")
]) - failure description: "JBAS014803: Duplicate resource [
    (\"subsystem\" => \"datasources\"),
    (\"data-source\" => \"ExampleDS\")
]"
```

How can I remove duplicate?

Comment: Open your `standalone.xml` and remove the duplicate resource.

Comment: Or rename the datasource you have added :)

Answer (score 35):

Under standalone/configuration/standalone-full.xml remove the duplicate deployment value.

Remove the below if mywar.war is the duplicate one.

```
<deployments>
    <deployment name="mywar.war" runtime-name="mywar.war">
        <content sha1="d642ffaa51228ab567439653a0923c69b7972cf5"/>
    </deployment>
</deployments>
```

Comment: Fixed the problem In my case. Looks like duplicated record was added from Idea IDE Jboss debug.

Comment: same problem as @David . Any way to stop IntelliJ from doing that?

Answer (score 17):

This is a bug about jboss. Please refer to https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1169239  for details.

To resolve the problem, try to find and remove the *** < app >.war.failed*** file.

Comment: Look within the JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments directory for this file. This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue. wildfly was also creating .failed files in standalone/configuration folder. To fix this,

- i removed all the .failed files.
- cleaned up the contents from deployments, tmp and data folders.
- started the server without any war/ear deployed. It was able to start clean.
- stopped the jboss and added the war/ear and started again

now it works fine. Looks like this is a known issue in WildFly
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-495

Hope this helps..

If this does not help. Next action to perform would be:
- Open the standalone.xml or standalone-full.xml (depending on which one is being used)

- find deployment-scanner tag. Most certainly it will have two or more entries.
- keep the entry mentioned below and remove all others:

deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" ....

- clear all the .failed files as well as tmp and data folders.
- try now to start jboss wildfly (you can add the war/ear again from eclipse jboss plugin).

Comment: Removing  `*.failed` plus WAR entry from `standalone.xml` deployments solved for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 method in this kind of  error :

- in standalone.xml  and remove the duplicate resource
  or in localhost:19990/console/App.html, you can too remove the duplicate resource

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some .jar was corrupted inside your maven local repository.

Delete all in `%UserProfile%\.m2\repository` directory, build and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @i2ijeya, I could solve thr problem. 
In my case, the XML block of **deployments** was in `standalone/configuration/standalone-full.xml` path.

Answer (score -1):

I also face this same issue, this is bug in JBOSS 8 version for this i follow the below steps to resolve this

1. remove *.failed files from deployments folder
2. comments below lines in standalone.xml file

   `<extension module="org.wildfly.extension.undertow"/>`

and this complete subsystem tag

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:1.2">
</subsystem>
```

3. restart JBoss
4. again remove `*.failed` files from deployement folder
5. uncomment step 2 means uncomment this tag

   `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:1.2">`

and

```
`<extension module="org.wildfly.extension.undertow"/>`
```

this line from standalone.xtml.

If you found removed this subsystem tag and above line from standalone.xml then copies these from standalone-full.xhtml.

6. restart the jboss and now this duplicate resource issue is resolved :)